# Visual Studio Codeでphpタグを挿入するショートカットはありますか？

Tags: php, vscode

PHPを一から勉強中でテキストエディタはVisual Studio Codeを使用しています。
`<?php></?php>`を何度も手入力しているのですが、便利なショートカットはないのでしょうか。
開発環境はXAMPPでPHPのフレームワークは特に使用していません。
PCのOSはWindows10です。

Comment: こんな [PHPの環境設定　with Visual Studio Code](https://qiita.com/y_murakami88/items/eafec8aa6ee8b09b57d8) のが参考になるのでは？

Answer (score 1):

`PHPタグ` や、 `関数やクラスの宣言` といったよく記述されるコードの断片を**スニペット**と呼び、Visual Studio Codeを含む多くのIDEでスニペットを挿入する機能が含まれています。

以下の記事を参考に、PHPタグのスニペットを作成してみてはいかがでしょうか。
[Creating your own snippets in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)

[Visual Studio Codeでユーザー独自のスニペットを定義する ｜ DevelopersIO](https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/how-to-add-your-own-code-snippets-of-visual-studio-code/)